# Log4j2 in Eclipse and Maven - need to have different config files

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j2

I am using Eclipse and m2e on my workstation.

Sometimes I run my unit tests individually with the built-in Eclipse JUnit functionality to display the results in the JUnit view.

At other times before checking in code, I run the whole test suite and integration tests using the Maven test goal.

However when I forget to change my log4j2 configuration to set the minimum log level to DEBUG, then the Maven process kills Eclipse and I need to restart.

I mostly set the log level to TRACE when I am running individual unit tests.

My log4j2 config file is in my src/test/resources directory.

I also have log4j2 set up in-container to read a config file on the file system.

Can I configure my Maven goal in the Eclipse Run dialog to use a different log4j2 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be quite simple.

Create a new config file src/test/resources/log4j2-maven.xml

Configure the surefire test runner in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
          <property>
            <name>log4j.configurationFile</name>
            <value>log4j2-maven.xml</value>
          </property>
        </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```